# Did anyone implement the app links introduced in Android M successfully?

Tags: android, applinks

I want to apply the Android M's App-Links mechanism to my company's app, after following the [google's guide](http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) and reading [this article](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-app-linking-how-it-works), I just couldn't get it work!

## error message :[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: Check this link http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#1

Comment: I mean app links which was introduced in Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SSL-certificate of your website https://www.alpha.elenet.me is not a valid one (valid in the term, that it is certified by a trust authority).

You should install a valid certificate on the website. As an alternative you try to implement the workarounds described by Google: [Security with HTTPS and SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've checked the source code,  the verification step is done by using httpUrlConnection to fire a http request to retrieve the assetlinks.json file on the website but not google mobile service,  so  I just wonder why  com.google.android.gms* appeared in my method stack?